# Designing UI in Flutter for Android

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter

Is it possible to design a Flutter UI via Android Studio by using a UI builder, like I would do when developing with Java/Kotlin?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, no.

But Flutter has something called [Hot Reload](https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/hot-reload), which allows you to see your chances within a second.

Flutter’s hot reload feature helps you quickly and easily experiment, build UIs, add features, and fix bugs. Hot reload works by injecting updated source code files into the running Dart Virtual Machine (VM). After the VM updates classes with the new versions of fields and functions, the Flutter framework automatically rebuilds the widget tree, allowing you to quickly view the effects of your changes.

There's also something called [Flutter Studio](https://flutterstudio.app/).

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I guess I'll stick with building using code. It's funny how Android Studio doesn't offer a WYSIWYG for Flutter, but does offer for Java/Kotlin

Comment: You can use https://flutterstudio.app/ too. Also accept the answer if it meets your expectations.

Comment: This is the kind of WYSIWYG I was looking for, yet it's not even close to what Android Studio offers, plus it seems to be buggy. I feel like in order to gain control over the layout, I need to program it myself.

Comment: You can also use https://app.flutterviz.com/ too. It's will make comple GUI project on exporting, to do make Front-end GUI as a whole!

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can try the Flutter UI Open-Source library. Try this GitHub repo for Flutter UI design [https://github.com/ionicfirebaseapp/getflutter](https://github.com/ionicfirebaseapp/getwidget)

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported right now. [Flutter Studio](https://flutterstudio.app/) doesn't look stable and have bugs in it. So the only preferable way up till now is to use [Hot Reload](https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/hot-reload). If you want to debug layout related issues, you can do the following:

1. import this in the root file (e.g. `main.dart`)

`import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';`

2. in your `main()` function, add these lines to enable layout debugging before `runApp()` method:

`debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;`

`debugPaintBaselinesEnabled = true;`

`debugPaintPointersEnabled = true;`

Answer (score -1):

yes offcourse ,mostly people using android studio - first install flutter and dart sdk .you also run in terminal flutter doctor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).